# plot data have aready be statisticed with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

original data

```
a = as.data.frame((cbind(c('a','a','b','a'),c(0,0,1,1))))
a
  V1 V2
1  a  0
2  a  0
3  b  1
4  a  1
```

plot a bar

```
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=V1,fill=factor(V1))) + geom_bar()
```

then i got this

[image]

but if i convert the data to this

```
a
  V1 V2 V2.number
1 a   0   2
2 a   1   1
3 b   1   1
```

i do this is becuse data is too big,i have to summary it

how could i get a picture like before?

Comment: How did you get the new `a`?

Comment: ohh I see, `V2` is the factor level and `V2.number` the number of records for each `V1` and `V2`...

Comment: yes，my data file is more then 1G,I have to summary it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use column `V2.number` as y values and add argument `stat="identity"` to `geom_bar()`.

```
ggplot(a,aes(V1,V2.number,fill=factor(V2)))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat_identity`:

```
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=V1, y=V2.number, fill=factor(V2))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
```